# What are best practices to call different methods based on a variable value in PHP?

Tags: php

From times to times you might need to call different functions based on a value of some variable. Something like this:

```
if ($var == 'someValue1') {
    $someObj->abc();
} elseif ...
} elseif ($var == 'someValueN') {
    $someObj->xyz();
}
```

There are many ways to accomplish this task in PHP. I've found 8 possible options:

1. Use a bunch of `if`/`else` statements
2. Use `switch` statement
3. Use variable functions
4. Use anonymous function (define an array of anonymous functions)
5. Use `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array` functions
6. Use polymorphism: abstract base class + a bunch of sub-classes
7. Use `eval` statement
8. Use `ReflectionMethod::invoke` method

It looks like these methods are situational. So, please, can you explain me in which situations I should use each of these options and why?

P.S.:
Here is an example of a situation when you might need to call different method based on a variable value:

```
/**
 * Checks if all needed parameters are present in the HTTP request
 * @param array $params Parameters which have to be present in the request
 * @throws MissingParameterException if any of the given parameters is missing
 */
public function checkParametersExistence($params)
{
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        $method = $param[0]; // a type of the param: get, post, put, delete
        $name = $param[1];   // a name of the param
        $code = $param[2];   // a code to send if this param is missing

        // $exists = $this->request->isGetParamSet($name);
        //     ... = $this->request->isPostParamSet($name);
        //     ... = $this->request->isPutParamSet($name);
        //     ... = $this->request->isDeleteParamSet($name);

        if ($exists == false) {
            throw new MissingParameterException($name, $code);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you show your real use case, you'll get more useful advice. The example you give looks pretty unlikely.

Comment: Agree with @MightyPork, question is too general. The general solution for me is - if you do need 10+ possible cases - 95% there is something to improve in application design.

Comment: @DWand maybe you are are trying to solve too much business cases with one controller/action? Try to separate at least different request types (GET/POST/...) with the router - it will be better. And maybe even use separate controller/action for every different request. Single responsibility works good for me.

Comment: _"which ways are better and which should be avoided?"_ ~ questions that evoke opinion based answers are considered off-topic here.

Comment: @Sparky, every opinion here can be confirmed by facts. Code works quicker - good. Code is more secure - good. Nobody can understand what is going on - bad. It is impossible to easily move the code from one server - bad. And so on... I think that best practices are based on practice. In some cases one way may be better, in some - another. That's why I'm interested to ask experienced people (who know what it is, who've worked with it, who've already tried some of these ways) how do they solve this case. And stackoverflow.com is one of the best places to find such professionals.

Comment: @Casey, in this particular example HTTP request, routing and controllers/actions are separated. Almost each action here has to check existence of all required parameters because it is an API and there are no warranty that a user has sent all of them. That's why I've decided to move this checking to a separate method of base controller class. But I'd like not to go in depth of this particular example because the question is more general.

Comment: API calls are generally method specific. For example, why would a read (using GET) need to work with POST or PUT or DELETE? I don't think it should.

Comment: @halfer, an intent of this method is to provide a general way to check all needed parameters for any action regardless of it's type (it could be either any of CRUD methods or a controller endpoint). So, it would be possible to replace a sequence of ```if (param1notexists){throw new exception} ... elseif (paramNnotexists){throw new exception}``` with a single method call. But, once again, I'd like not to go in depth of this particular example.

Comment: I think it might help to go in depth in this particular example, so we can understand your general case. Are you writing a router? Do you want to hold a set of validations per endpoint in order to see if the call has been made correctly (and let it progress onto the business logic)?

Comment: @halfer, okay. Each action has to check existence of all required parameters. I have a sequence of ```if/else``` in each action, it looks ugly and it will require too many corrections in case something changes. So, I want to move this logic to a separate method. In a compiled language (most likely) I would choose the 6th way: create a base class like ParamValidator + a bunch of validators for each request method. But in PHP each class has to be found in FS and interpreted. Also it has additional ways to solve this task, and maybe some of them are better depending on specifics of the language.

Comment: "Each action has to check existence of all required parameters" - that still sounds like something your router could do. But if there is a reason why you could not do that, then maybe call a list of validators in a check method, but rather than them using `if/else`, get them to throw an exception if they fail. You'll then just have a list of validators in a validation method, which seems tidy and readable enough.

Comment: @halfer, thank you. But how can a router know that my CreateSausage action requires a "meatType" parameter to be present in a body of POST request? The ```checkParametersExistence``` method in general executes a list of validators. For this particular example the question is: what is the best way to implement validator calls as there are at least 8 ways to do that? And also I do want to know which ways are better for which situations in general.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I'm thinking of URL/GET routing - for example `/SausageSearch/:meatType` would specify that a meat type string is mandatory for this end point. See the routing section for Slim or Silex if you want to know more about that - they often have syntaxes to make parameters optional, to apply regex conditions, etc. Usually if these validations fail, the route is ignored, which is usually what is required. Of course, you can be more permissive in the router and then raise errors in the handler if you prefer.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less opinion-based. Hope this will help. I don't know how to make it more deterministic and keep general enough at the same time. I really want to know why each of these approaches should(not) be used (not just "this is good, this is bad"). Moreover, some of them are unique for PHP and are absent in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a bit general but **in most cases** using swtich statement or bunch of if-elses **is the worst choice** because:

1. After a while it will be really hard to read or/and understand this code.
2. Those constructions are hard to extend because they often break [Dependency Inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

That's why, depending on the particular case, you can consider using design patterns like:

1. [Factory Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)
2. [Bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern)
3. [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)
4. ... or something else ;)

### EDIT:

In attached code you can consider checking method first (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE etc.) and after this searching for params in exact request type.. But I'm not sure what is purpose of this logic so I can be wrong ;)

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprised that there are no general recommendations of which approach to use in different situations. Finally, as a result of Googling, asking and thinking I've got the following conclusion: it is necessary to take in account a general purpose of an approach and to think why this functionality was added. It is an interesting theme for a little research. However, I'll accept this answer as the most useful of all given. Thank you, @Arius.

Answer (score 3):

I've just written a simple benchmark based on validation example from the question to compare execution speed of these approaches.

A test executes a validation loop 1000 times. Tests are repeated 25 times to get an average execution time. The code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/DWand/54ae49470ee8557432a3

Machine configuration:

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7400 2.8GHz, RAM: 4Gb
- Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1
- PHP Version 5.4.11

I've got the following results:

- Test "If/Else sequense": 0.01506411552429199 sec.
- Test "Switch": 0.01624316215515137 sec.
- Test "Variable functions": 0.02013579368591309 sec.
- Test "Anonymous functions": 0.1487146759033203 sec.
- Test "Function call_user_func": 0.1564707851409912 sec.
- Test "Function eval": 0.2150658702850342 sec.
- Test "Reflection": 0.02306700706481933 sec.
- Test "Polymorphism": 0.02339528083801269 sec.

These approaches could be grouped based on execution speed:

- If/Else, Switch (~ 0.016 sec)
- Variable functions, ReflectionMethod, Polymorphism (~ 0.023 sec)
- Anonymous functions, call_user_func (~ 0.14-0.15 sec)
- eval (~ 0.21 sec)

As these results are made of 1000 * 7 executions of a statement, it could be considered that execution speed is almost the same. `eval` function, anonymous functions and `call_user_func` function might be candidates to avoid because they are slower.

Comment: Nice comparison, it may be quite useful :)

Comment: Freaking awesome.  I am trully impressed you had taking the time. And thank you

Answer (score 0):

For scripting:
I prefer switch statements.

It seems to me back in my c++/school days switch were more efficient (doesn't meant php's implimentation is).

For OOP:

```
$someObj->func($varable)

private function    func($action)
{
   switch($action)
   {

   }

}
```

Comment: Please format code statements using Markdown, as per MightyPork's edit. Also, did you mean to prefix that function with `function`, so PHP knows what it is?

Comment: My bad  I get lazy with code I don't intend to run